# How can I convert between enum and cstring without map?

Tags: c++, enums

I've seen this answered before but using map or vectors, but I can't use outside libraries for my project, so I need to figure out another way. For converting to a cstring I'm using a function with a switch case and it works, but for converting from a cstring to the enum isn't going as planned.

The method I came up with for converting a cstring to an enum is to first cast the enum to an int (none, first, second, etc.. becomes 0, 1, 2, etc...) so that I can use a for loop to iterate through the different enums. Next, using the enum to cstring function, I compare the string passed in to the string given by the converting function. If they are equal, the enum is set. This seems like a pretty convoluted way to do this, and unsurprisingly, I can't get it working.

Here's all my test code, the setType function is where things go wrong.

```
enum type { none, first, second, third, fourth };

const char* typeName(type name);
type setType(char* name);                   // trouble here
int myStrComp(const char *str1, const char *str2);  // compare cstrings

int main() {                                // test the function
    char testName[] = "second";
    type testType = setType(testName);
    std::cout << typeName(testType) << std::endl;   // should print "second"
}

const char* typeName(type name) {           // convert enum to cstring
    switch (name) {
    case none:      return '\0';        break;
    case first:     return "first";     break;
    case second:    return "second";    break;
    case third:     return "third";     break;
    case fourth:    return "fourth";    break;
    }
}

type setType(char* name) {
    type temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {       // I know, inefficient
        temp = static_cast<type>(i);    // but there's only 5 to check
        if (myStrComp(name, typeName(temp)) == 0) {
            return temp;
        }
    }
    return none;    // shouldn't get here
}

int myStrComp(const char *str1, const char *str2) {
    while (*str1 == *str2) {
        if (!*str1) {
            return 0;           // strings are equal
        }
        str1++;
        str2++;
    }
    return *str1 - *str2;   // how different are they alphabetically
}
```

Comment: For contiguous enumerated values you could use a plain, old array.

Comment: Unrelated: `case none:      return '\0';` Wrong quotes.

Comment: The code you posted _is_ using "outside libraries": `std::cout `. And what is the reason for this limitation?

Comment: Please share the details about **how** exactly it's not working: 1. what are you doing? 2. what is happening? 3. what should have happened?

Comment: @user4581301 Hmmm... why didn't I think of that before struggling with this for hours. Anyway, I'd still like to know how to do it so I can use the words in place of literal ints all over my code. It would make it more readable. First, second, etc.. are just placeholders.

Comment: @NeilButterworth iostream and fstream are the exceptions. The restrictions are because this is a school assignment. I'm supposed to struggle with this before I earn the right to use strings and whatnot.

Comment: @griffin175, using strings instead of enum values would be actually kind of a "bad tone". You are already using words instead of numbers by using enum values, that is exactly what enums are for - to give names to numeric values.

Comment: @r3musn0x The consol prints nothing and ends the program. Some kind of runtime error. This is all I know, you can compile it yourself if you can find out more from that.

Comment: @griffin175, that's strange. I've tried it and it works for me. It outputs "second" just as it should be.

Comment: @griffin175 had to fix two compiler errors, but it works:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e77d200a07da4c8

Comment: @r3musn0x @R2RT It was the just the `'\0'` the whole time! That was stupid of me, thanks @user4581301 for pointing that out. When the compare function saw that in the first pass of the loop in `setType(char*)` it broke.

Comment: griffin175 I recommend fixing the other error @R2RT mentions: There is no `return` for the case where `name` is not handled in the `switch`. I'd probably throw (and deliberately not catch) an exception here because it should never happen. That said, an array will eliminate the need for the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case none:      return '\0';        break;
```

This has single quotes, so it returns character `\0`, which as an integer is equal to 0. When converted to pointer, this is [a null pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Null_pointers). When you try to dereference a null pointer in `myStrComp()`, [an access violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) happens.

Instead, you can use `return "";` to return an empty string.

Possible way to simplify `typeName` is to use an array:

```
const char* typeName[] = {"", "first", "second", "third", "fourth"};
if (myStrComp(name, typeName[i]) == 0)
```

(This will cause access violation if `i` is out of bounds.)

Comment: Would suggest the array and its contents be  `constexpr`, although a modern compiler should be able to optimize `static const char* const typeName[]` just as well. In addition to being more efficient, if anything modifies the entries, that’s a major bug, so we want the compiler to catch it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your *question*, you can associate `enum`s with text by using a lookup table:

```
struct Entry
{
  type  enum_type;
  const char * enum_text;
};

Entry enum_conversion_table[] =
{
    {none, "none"},
    {first, "first"},
    {second, "second"},
    {third,  "third"},
    {fourth, "fourth"},
};
static const size_t conversion_table_capacity =
    sizeof(conversion_table) / sizeof(conversion_table[0]);
```

### Converting from `enum` to text:

1. Search the table for an entry with the key enum.
2. Return a pointer to the text field of the entry, if found, or nullptr if not found.

### Converting from text to `enum`:

1. Search the table for an entry with the key enum text.
2. Return the enum value if found, or create another enum value for "unknown" and return that.

This technique:
1. Doesn't use any libraries.
2. The data can be placed into the constant data section and stored into read-only memory.
3. The code can access the data directly.
4. The data is initialized before `main()`.